# turn "string-like" list into int with python

Tags: python, pandas

After after retrieving some data, some rows of my `dataframe` are composed by "string-like" lists, like this one:

```
       bar                foo
   0     'A'                1
   1     'B'                2
   2     'B'     "['2' ,'3']"
   3     'B'              '4'
   4     'C'     "['5' ,'3']"
```

How could I turn the `foo` column into `int` values and take the bigger value with `python` `pandas`?

Comment: That is not a "string-like" list. That is *a string*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Warning. This is kinda manual;

```
df['foo']=df['foo'].str.strip("''")#Strip ''
df['foo']=np.where(df['foo'].str.contains('\['),df['foo'].str.findall('(?<=\"\[\')\d(?=\'\,)|(?<=\')\d(?=\'\]\")'),df['foo'])# Extract digits sandwitched between special characters
df['foo']=df['foo'].explode().max(level = 0)



  bar foo
0  'A'   1
1  'B'   2
2  'B'   3
3  'B'   4
4  'C'   5
```

Comment: I had to dig a bit into the errors but finally worked.
The final snippet worked this way:
df['foo']=df['foo'].explode().max(level = 0)#Explode dataframe

Comment: Thanks, silly mistake on my part. It cant be a tuple. Edited

Answer (score 3):

#### `literal_eval`

```
from ast import literal_eval

df.foo.map(literal_eval).explode().max(level=0)

0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
Name: foo, dtype: object
```

---

However, if some elements are already non-string objects

```
from ast import literal_eval

def l_eval(x):
    try:
        return literal_eval(x)
    except ValueError as e:
        return x

df.foo.map(l_eval).explode().max(level=0)
```

Comment: Not quite - that gets them halfway, but they want the `max()` too!

Comment: @ti7 thx, fixed

Comment: this method throws the following error message in my terminal:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "../lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 50, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, flags,

  File "<unknown>", line 1
    2; 1
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Should it be a problem with the ast.py file?

Comment: No, i don't think so.  Almost certainly it is that one of the values you are passing isn't a valid python literal.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `literal_eval` to transform the foo column and then **if the element is a list** you get the `max`

```py
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval

...

df.foo = df.foo.map(lambda x: literal_eval(str(x)))
"""
  bar     foo
0   A       1
1   B       2
2   B  [2, 3]
3   B       4
4   C  [5, 3]
"""

df.foo = df.foo.map(lambda x: max(x) if isinstance(x, list) else x)
"""
  bar foo
0   A   1
1   B   2
2   B   3
3   B   4
4   C   5
"""
```

```py
def get_max(item):
    item = literal_eval(str(item))
    return max(item) if isinstance(item, list) else item

df.foo = df.foo.map(get_max)
```